# how to count the values of an array

Tags: php, arrays, count

i have this array:

```
$questions = [
    1 => 'Question 1',
    2 => 'Question 2',
    3 => 'Question 3',
    4 => 'Question 4',
    5 => 'Question 5',
    ];
```

How can i count the values of this array? It should give as output `5`

Comment: Google really couldn't help with this: `php array count`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo count($questions); // output 5
```